# Problem in memcpy using non-char data as parameters!

Tags: c, memcpy

The following program doesn't output desired data (on VC2008 compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int dest[10] = {1};
    int src [] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    memcpy(dest, src, 5);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%i\n", dest[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

whereas using `char` arrays instead, every thing goes fine!
where is the problem here?

Comment: It doesn't output the desired data....
What does it output, and what is desired?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

memcpy takes a number of bytes to copy - not a number of objects.

```
 memcpy(dest,src,5*sizeof(dest[0]))
```

Comment: `5 * sizeof dest[0]`, or `sizeof src`, may be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` copies bytes only. you need to tell it how many bytes to copy by multiplying the number of objects by the size of each object like so:

```
memcpy(dest, src, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `memcpy(dest,scr,sizeof(int)*5)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `sizeof(int)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int dest[10] = {1};
    int src [] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(int) * 5);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%i\n", dest[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call memcpy with a `sizeof( x )` where "x" stands for the object.  Here you'd do

```
memcpy( dest, src, 5*sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: Ah! Almost. You were on the right track: **where "x" stands for the object.** Try `memcpy(dest, src, sizeof src);`

Answer (score 0):

Better is

```
memcpy( dest, src, 5*sizeof*src) );
```

If you change array-type  to an other type, the code must **not** changed.